# power shield delete older emails than 6 month

Tags: powershell

i have code like this:

```
Search-Mailbox -Identity test@test.com -SearchQuery '(Received:01/12/2017..01/14/2020)' -deletecontent
```

i need  delete older emails than 6 month, how to do it? i know is function "get-date" but how minus 6 month?
i try

```
 Search-Mailbox -Identity test@test.com -SearchQuery '(Received:01/12/2017..'(get-date).AddMonths(-12).ToString("MM/dd/yyy")')' -deletecontent
```

but i get error

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '07/27/2019'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Search-Mailbox], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Search-Mailbox
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

Comment: Your searchQuery string isn't build correctly. Currently you have one string `'(Received:01/12/2017..'` then `(get-date).AddMonths(-12).ToString("MM/dd/yyy")` and finaly the last string `')'`> Better: `"(Received:01/12/2017..$((get-date).AddMonths(-12).ToString("MM/dd/yyy")))"`

Comment: And you should be using `AddMonths(-6)` to match your question title and body. e.g. `Search-Mailbox  -Identity test@test.com -SearchQuery Received:<"$((Get-Date).AddMonths(-6).ToString('MM/dd/yyy'))" -DeleteContent -Force`